# inconsequent behaviour of div's

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I have a site running WordPress. The design of the homepage looks right half of the time and wrong the other half. The fact that it doesn't always makes it hard for me to understand what is happening and solve the issue. I can reproduce the issue by refreshing the specific page in chrome and IE, I did not check other browsers.

The page I am talking about is here:
http://boat-hotel.com/index.php/nl/

Below the main image there should be 3 columns of text. Attached you find a screenshot of the page that doesn't show right. [screenshot of error occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDJVv.png)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use `clear: both` style to the container of your 3 columns. With no HTML and CSS from you I can tthink only of that.

Answer (score 0):

Your div with the id "featured" had 0 height, and so the "controller" and "content-area" divs pushed themselves up behind the slideshow.  Try setting a height on the "featured" div. `330px` worked fairly well for me.

I think its getting 0 height because your slide divs inside are absolutely positioned, which removes them from the page flow and doesn't force a size on your "featured" div.

Comment: Thanks! I have set the heigth

Comment: Wauw, thanks! I have set the height to 332 and it is solved! I am very greatful!

Answer (score 0):

Set a height of `332px` on your `#feature`d div.

The reason you're seeing the page right half the time and wrong half the time is due to the time it's taking your script for the slideshow to load. Setting the height on #featured will save the proper amount of space in the page.

Comment: Wauw, thanks! I have set the height to 332 and it is solved! I am very greatful!